# limit the array length by 2 data only

Tags: javascript

I am currently making a matchmaking system. **My target is to limit the array length by 2 data only**. In my current work, when I add another data with the same level, it becomes 3 data in 1 array (Please see pic 1). When there's 3 data in 1 array, send the extra 1 data to another array until it gets a player to match with. **The matching works when players have the same level**. I have provided my codes below and a screenshot. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

```js
const source = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'player1',
    level: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'player2',
    level: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'player3',
    level: 2
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'player4',
    level: 2
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'player5',
    level: 1
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: 'player6',
    level: 3
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: 'player7',
    level: 3
  },



]
const combine = (source) => {
  return source.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (acc[curr.level])
      acc[curr.level].push(curr);
    else
      acc[curr.level] = [curr];
    return acc;
  }, {})
}
var result = combine(source)
var html = ""
var keys = Object.keys(result) //if there more then one keys i.e : 2..

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  console.log("Keys " + keys[i])
  //loop through json array
  result[keys[i]].forEach(function(val, index) {
  //check if index value is `0`..change name. 
    var ids = index == 0 ? "id[]" : "idside[]"
    var name = index == 0 ? "name[]" : "nameside[]"
    var levels = index == 0 ? "level[]" : "levelside[]"
    html += `<input type="text" name="${ids}" value="${val.id}">
<input type="text" name="${name}" value="${val.name}">
<input type="text" name="${levels}" value="${val.level}">`
  })
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html //add html to div

console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: Ok what do you want to do with third object that has `evel 1`? Ignore it?

Comment: Send it to the 4th array without a match until i gets a player with the same level. I'm sorry i forgot to specify it. I'll edit it now.

Comment: with what level number??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accumulate into a 2d array by level and check if the currently accumulated array length is 2.

```js
const
  source = [{ id: 1, name: 'player1', level: 1 }, { id: 2, name: 'player2', level: 1 }, { id: 3, name: 'player3', level: 2 }, { id: 4, name: 'player4', level: 2 }, { id: 5, name: 'player5', level: 1 }, { id: 6, name: 'player6', level: 3 }, { id: 7, name: 'player7', level: 3 },];

const combine = (source) => {
  return source.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (acc[curr.level]) {
      const levelArr = acc[curr.level];
      const last = levelArr[levelArr.length - 1];
      if (last.length === 2) {
        levelArr.push([curr])
      } else {
        last.push(curr);
      }
    }
    else {
      acc[curr.level] = [[curr]];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
};

const result = combine(source)

// HTML generation
const matchesUl = document.createElement('ul');

Object.entries(result).forEach(([key, level]) => {
  const levelLi = document.createElement('li');
  const title = document.createTextNode(`Level ${key}`);
  levelLi.appendChild(title);
  const levelUl = document.createElement('ul');
  levelLi.appendChild(levelUl);
  level.forEach(match => {
    const [p1, p2] = match;
    const matchLi = document.createElement('li');
    matchLi.textContent = `${p1.name} vs. ${p2?.name ?? '-'}`;
    levelUl.appendChild(matchLi);
  })
  matchesUl.appendChild(levelLi);
})

document.getElementById("result").appendChild(matchesUl); //add html to div

// Debug
const pre = document.createElement('pre')
pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);

document.getElementById('debug').appendChild(pre);
```

```css
 #debug {
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>

<div id="debug">
  <p>Output</p>
</div>
```

---

If you only want complete combinations you can track individual players in an `unmatched` object and only add them to their applicable level array when a match is found. You will still end up with a 2D array for each level, but all sub-arrays will be matched pairs.

```js
const
  source = [{ id: 1, name: 'player1', level: 1 }, { id: 2, name: 'player2', level: 1 }, { id: 3, name: 'player3', level: 2 }, { id: 4, name: 'player4', level: 2 }, { id: 5, name: 'player5', level: 1 }, { id: 6, name: 'player6', level: 3 }, { id: 7, name: 'player7', level: 3 }, { id: 8, name: 'player8', level: 3 }];

const combine = (source) => {
  return source.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (acc[curr.level]) {
      if (acc.unmatched[curr.level]) {
        acc[curr.level].push([acc.unmatched[curr.level], curr])
        acc.unmatched[curr.level] = null;
      } else {
        acc.unmatched[curr.level] = curr;
      }
    }
    else {
      acc[curr.level] = [];
      acc.unmatched[curr.level] = curr;
    }
    return acc;
  }, { unmatched: {} })
};

const result = combine(source)

// HTML Generation
const matchesUl = document.createElement('ul');

Object.entries(result).forEach(([key, level]) => {
  if (key !== 'unmatched') {
    const levelLi = document.createElement('li');
    const title = document.createTextNode(`Level ${key}`);
    levelLi.appendChild(title);
    const levelUl = document.createElement('ul');
    levelLi.appendChild(levelUl);
    level.forEach(match => {
      const [p1, p2] = match;
      const matchLi = document.createElement('li');
      matchLi.textContent = `${p1.name} vs. ${p2?.name ?? '-'}`;
      levelUl.appendChild(matchLi);
    });
    matchesUl.appendChild(levelLi);
  }
});

const unmatchedLi = document.createElement('li');
const title = document.createTextNode('Unmatched');
unmatchedLi.appendChild(title);
const unmatchedUl = document.createElement('ul');
unmatchedLi.appendChild(unmatchedUl);
Object.values(result.unmatched).forEach(player => {
  if (player) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = `${player.name} (lvl ${player.level})`;
    unmatchedUl.appendChild(li);
  }
});
matchesUl.appendChild(unmatchedLi)

document.getElementById("result").appendChild(matchesUl); //add html to div

// Debug
const pre = document.createElement('pre')
pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);

document.getElementById('debug').appendChild(pre);
```

```css
#debug {
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
  }
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>

<div id="debug">
  <p>Output</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is correct, because when I added a new data to match with the 3rd data in the 1st array, it works. https://prnt.sc/16vxelk Thank you. :D

Comment: Hello, just a little question, i wonder why is it still on the 1st array count? Is it supposed to be in the 4th array?   https://prnt.sc/16vxuz6

Comment: You now have 2D arrays for each level, this means you will need to adjust your html generation to match. The alternative is to increment level keys in the out object but this gets messy quite quickly. (I also don't know what you mean by '4th array')

Comment: https://prnt.sc/16wbzj0 << the 2 players with level "1" should be on the next array rather than being joined on the 1st array, right? Or it's acceptable? Sorry i'm a newbie. So i'm just asking. Hope you won't take it in a bad way. Thank you

Comment: Your `combine` function is a 'group by' operation grouping elements by their level property so their is no '4th array' unless there is a player with a level of 4. If you want a 1 dimensional array as a result you can flatten the result values, but the nested array structure of my first answer is the cleanest solution given your initial code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `acc[curr.level].length > 1` in `combine` method as below to check if there are more than two player in one level, ignore that:

```js
  const source = [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'player1',
            level: 1
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'player2',
            level: 1
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'player3',
            level: 2
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: 'player4',
            level: 2
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            name: 'player5',
            level: 1
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            name: 'player6',
            level: 3
        },
        {
            id: 7,
            name: 'player7',
            level: 3
        },



        ]
        const combine = (source) => {
            return source.reduce((acc, curr) => {
                if (acc[curr.level] && acc[curr.level].length > 1)
                    return acc;
                if (acc[curr.level])
                    acc[curr.level].push(curr);
                else
                    acc[curr.level] = [curr];
                return acc;
            }, {})
        }
        var result = combine(source)
        var html = ""
        var keys = Object.keys(result) //if there more then one keys i.e : 2..

        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            console.log("Keys " + keys[i])
            //loop through json array
            result[keys[i]].forEach(function (val, index) {
                //check if index value is `0`..change name.
                var ids = index == 0 ? "id[]" : "idside[]"
                var name = index == 0 ? "name[]" : "nameside[]"
                var levels = index == 0 ? "level[]" : "levelside[]"
                html += `<input type="text" name="${ids}" value="${val.id}">
            <input type="text" name="${name}" value="${val.name}">
            <input type="text" name="${levels}" value="${val.level}">`
            })
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = html //add html to div

        console.log(result);
```

```html
 <div id="result">
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello, I added   { id: 8, name: 'player8', level: 1}, so i just get to see if the extra data in my first array would be matched with the added one. But it is not working, it gone missing. 

https://prnt.sc/16vwxye << Please see this